# JPA - EntityGraph and Hibernate L2 Cache (ehcache)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I have a one-to-many relationship defined as below

```
@Cacheable
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Parent.Child",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("children"),
    }
)
public class Parent {
    private Set<Child> children;
    // getter - setter
}
```

Now in my DAL, i'm calling this method

```
@Override
    public Parent getParentWithChildren(int id) {
        EntityGraph<?> graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("Parent.Child");
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
        return entityManager.find(Parent.class, id, props);
    }
```

Since i have loaded Parent with Children, i should be able to use **children** collection outside of the transaction. But i'm getting **Lazyinitialization Exception**. This happens only when hibernate level 2 cache - ehcache is enabled. If i disable it from config, it works as expected. Also if i initialize collection explicitly after **find**, it works as expected. So is it a bug?. I'm using Hibernate 5.2.6.Final with JPA 2.1.

EDIT: One more thing i noticed was that entity loads fine for the first time, so that problem must be related with hibernate & cache provider.

Comment: I experience similar situation. I don't use L2 cache. I realized, that if entity is already in persistence context, next em.find with fetchgraph hint doesn't load anything from the database. It seems to me as bug as well.

Comment: I think same happens for session cache as well. This is a confirmed bug and it is marked to be resolved in 5.2.10

Answer (score 1):

In order for Hibernate to use an entity graph one must bypass the second-level cache (e.g. EhCache) by using the `javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode` hint with the value `CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS`:

```java
final EntityGraph<?> graph = em.getEntityGraph("myGraph");
final Map<String, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
hints.put("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);
hints.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
final SomeEntity entity = em.find(SomeEntity.class, 42, hints);
```

Note that the second-level cache will still be populated as usual.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not a bug. I guess Hibernate is delaying the loading from cache until really necessary. The implementation can decide to be lazy as see fit unless you ask for eager fetching.

So the general rule is to load everything you need before going out of the transaction (before closing the Hibernate session to be precise).

Comment: I'm already using fetch graph to eagerly load children collection

Comment: You are not giving enough information for me to prove it but I suspect that it is in fact the objects in the collection that are proxied to be lazily loaded.

Comment: See the props object. Im specifying fetch graph